# vba importexportspecification not working twice

Tags: import-from-csv

Seems `CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("import-CP_Commandes").Execute` has sometimes a strange behaviour.
I need to import daily one or several csv files that will be inserted into an access database. Each file is previously copied in a file named CP_Commandes.csv. I have written a VBA function within Access to do the job.
I have created the necessary importexport specification (named import-CP_Commandes). The relevant xml is stored in a txt file. It works fine with the first file, i.e. the CP_commandes.csv is imported into the relevant Access table (x_temp_commandes). Problem is, after copying the next file into CP_commandes.csv, Executing the import does just nothing, without any error. It looks like Access considers it has already done the job ! Even after stopping the program and re-launching, same result : x_temp_commandes is empty !
After some time, maybe an hour or more, I cant' be more precise, the second file is treated OK ...

I tried different solutions for file #2 to cope with this problem.

Solution 1 :

```
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("import-CP_Commandes").delete
DoEvents
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.add "import-CP_Commandes",ch  '(ch previously loaded from the relevant xml file)
DoEvents
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("import-CP_Commandes").Execute
=> no error, x_temp_commandes empty
```

Solution 2 :
Same as solution 1, but with ch modified to specify the actual file to be imported instead of `CP_Commandes.csv => no error, x_temp_commandes empty`.

But sometimes, the program without ANY modification is able to import 2 or 3 files without problem.

Hence my question : Is there something I can do to make sure the work will be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I finally figured it out - I was not closing the recordset which I oped with

`set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("x_Temp_CP_Commandes")`

For this reason, Import did not work - but it did not mention an error. By applying an `rs.close` after this, the following files import correctly.